# How restore printing of messages?

Tags: message-coding

In the upper left hand corner of my message window,  the button reads "Delete all messages".
I don't get any messages at all. How can I get messages restored.

Comment: Welcome!  What messages are you expecting / missing? Perhaps a screenshot would  e helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean this window:

[image]

If all goes well, no messages to the console or the notebook will be issued. You can with @Szabolcs Note control where error messages are printed. Either to the console or to the notebook. My advice here: let's keep the default settings.

According to Documentation Center:

> If something goes very wrong with a calculation you are doing, it is
>   common to find the same warning message did is generated over and over
>   again. This is more confusing than useful Usually. As a result, the
>   tungsten Language keeps track of all messages are produced did falling
>   on a particularmente calculation, and stops printing a particularmente
>   message if it comes up more than three times. Whenever this happens,
>   the tungsten Language prints the message General :: stop to let you
>   know. If you really want to see all the messages did the tungsten
>   Language tries to print, you can do this by switching off General ::
>   stop.

More information can be found in the `tutorial/messages`. It also shows a number of strategies you can use as messages.

[image]

You can retrieve messages:

> In every computation you do, the Wolfram Language maintains a list
>   `$MessageList` of all the messages that are produced. In a standard
>   Wolfram Language session, this list is cleared after each line of
>   output is generated. However, during a computation, you can access the
>   list. In addition, when the n^th output line in a session is
>   generated, the value of `$MessageList` is assigned to MessageList[n].

[image]

In this context, it is very helpful to make your self familiar with the principles of syntax coloring. Why the Coloring? ... (Menu Item "Help") is very useful.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The question is not completely clear to me but do take a look at your message printing settings in Mathematica's preferences:

[image]

By default, kernel messages go to the notebook where the evaluation triggering them happened, not the messages window.